# How to get dynamic shell variable with Ansible playbook and jinja2 templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I need to call a shell script that will return the private ip of an ec2 in an Ansible task. 
Once I get the IP in a variable `private_ip_var` I want to inject that variable in a jinja2 template to generate a config file.

Here's what I'm thinking:

```
- hosts: all
    vars:
    inline_variable: 'hello again'
    tasks:
    - name: Gets the IP of the ec2 instance 
    command: get_ec2_private_ip.sh   <----- shell script to dynamically get the ip of ec2
    register: private_ip_var`  <------ saving shell return value to this var

    tasks:
    - name: Inject that private_ip_var into the jinja template
        template:
        src: src=config.cfg.j2
        dest: config.cfg
```

### ***config.cfg.j2***

```
blah blah 
The ip of the ec2 is: {{ private_ip_var }}  <------------ THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE
Variable given as inline - {{ inline_variable }}  <------------- DONT CARE ABOUT THIS VAR
```

***output - config.cfg***

```
------
blah blah
The ip of the ec2 is: 10-251-50-12  <----------------- THIS IS WHAT I WANT
Variable given as inline - hello again <---------------- DONT CARE ABOUT THIS VAR
```

I don't care about `inline_variable` above; I only care about `private_ip_var`; how can I achieve this with Ansible so that i can generate that config file from a jinja2 template?

Answer (score 0):

To get AWS EC2 information, you will need to install the following on your (Linux) host:

- boto3
- botocore
- Python >= 2.6

Then use the module `ec2_instance_info`. Here is an example:

```
ec2_instance_info:
instance_ids:
  - i-23456789
```

Then you can filter on ip address information. You will most likely be interested in the following parameters:

`primary` (true / false)

- Indicates whether this IPv4 address is the primary private IP address of the network interface.

For more examples, check out: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_instance_info_module.html#examples

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, assuming that I already have a shell script that pulls down that ec2 info, my question is more around, how do I call that shell script in such a way that it passes that ip address dynamically to a template.yaml (cloudformation) for example via jinja2 templates in ansible? My question isn't about how to extract that info from ec2; but more about how to pass that extracted ip or dns over to a template.yaml so that the next step in the build can launch an cloudformation stack for example!